# Is it possible to take screenshots in HTMLUnit driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

So far i browsed the same topic over the internet but not getting the right answer.

I want to execute the script/suite with HTMLUnit driver but it getting fail and showing exception:

> Exception while taking screenshot
>   org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver cannot be cast to
>   org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot

As I understood it got stuck at Screenshot capturing code. So my question is . Is there any way to capture screenshot while executing script using HTMLUnit driver ?

Because in My framework  i'm calling the common takeScreenshot method from so many places wherever any change happening on the page like:

`before filling the form --> after filling the form --> after submit the form`

So  i can't remove all those method call from whole suite.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I've found is [this extended HTMLUnitDriver](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-developers/PTR_j4xLVRM/k2yVq01Fa7oJ).
For more context, see also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36254656/not-able-to-take-screenshot-using-htmlunitdriver-selenium-webdriver-java).

Following the comments on that question, why not use PhantomJS, which apparently supports screenshots?

Comment: you are right, I have tried with PhantomJS driver, it's working fine but my concern is about htmlUnit

Comment: PhantomJS is no longer developed.